# Kendo Excel export & rowSpan

Tags: javascript, excel, kendo-ui, html-table, openxml

I try to export data to xlsx using kendo.ooxml.Workbook. It says that I can use rowSpan, but it seems to be buggy. When I set different rowspan for columns A and B, the last two cells in column C will disappear:

```
var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
    sheets: [
        {
            rows: [
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "a", rowSpan: 3 },
                        { value: "b", rowSpan: 2 },
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "b", rowSpan: 4 },
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "a", rowSpan: 3 },
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
});

kendo.saveAs({
    dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
    fileName: "Test.xlsx"
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/92ggxnxn/

But if I set the same rowspan for A and B columns, the C column will contain all the values:

```
var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
    sheets: [
        {
            rows: [
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "a", rowSpan: 3 },
                        { value: "b", rowSpan: 3 },
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "a", rowSpan: 3 },
                        { value: "b", rowSpan: 3 },
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    cells: [
                        { value: "c"},
                        { value: "d"},
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
});

kendo.saveAs({
    dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
    fileName: "Test.xlsx"
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pb349fx2/

Is it a bug, or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was definitely a bug. It should be fixed in the latest release. See the updated snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/92ggxnxn/1/

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's true, back then I've contacted the support and they answered that they'll fix it someday, but won't email me back because they're too busy. So I redid the project with excelbuilderjs.